MySQL table with partitions on multiple remote servers (only partitions)
in PostgreSQL you can create a table with let's say 4 partitions (hash)
and locate each partition on different servers (remote PostgreSQL servers) and it's called (Foreign Data Wrapper). Now in MySQL i heard there is a Federated engine which you can connect to a remote server with it but it just work for a table not its partitions. I know i can use NDB but i want to have multiple MySQL servers and manage data spread by my self (based on the table partitions). Is there any solution in MySQL to make a table (Innodb) and spread its partitions on multiple remote MySQL servers ?

You have described a solution that is not working.  Please describe the problem you are trying to solve.

MySQL's Federated storage engine does not support partitioning. You can define a table whose storage resides on a different MySQL Server, but not for a table with partitions. Besides that, the Federated storage engine has other limitations, and I don't recommend it.
PlanetScale is probably the best solution for what you describe. It's not built-in to MySQL. It's a separate company with their own software you use together with MySQL. PlanetScale handles a lot of the complex work required to maintain partitioned data on multiple servers.
Another possible solution is ProxySQL. They have a guide on how to use ProxySQL for "sharding," which is the popular term for splitting a table over multiple servers as you describe. See https://proxysql.com/documentation/how-to-setup-proxysql-sharding/
Any distributed data solution is going to be a lot more difficult than a single database server. You should consider carefully whether this is the right solution, or if you can continue using a single database server if you optimize the table and queries.

My project is a Messenger so absolutely i need distributed data ... I'm going to check your solutions but i think it's better after all to use MariaDB spider engine ! What do you think ?

I have not used the spider storage engine. It is included with MariaDB, but not MySQL. For MySQL, you would have to download and install Spider yourself.  It appears to be a project of a solo developer in Japan. I don't find any documentation. Support is by email. I'd feel pretty unsure about relying on this for important data.

By the way, it does not follow that a messenger application necessarily needs a distributed database architecture. The reasons to use distributed data are either that you have high write traffic that a single server can't keep up with, or the size of data grows larger than a single server can store.

Well, Spider is part of the MariaDB project and it's not like a solo project ! In fact, i heard too much about Mariadb and Galera + Spider and this is its document. ... https://mariadb.com/kb/en/spider-storage-engine-overview/ but i don't know about using Spider on MySQL ... because i think it's designed for MariaDB ... but i have problem with mariadb too because the lack of bson support (mariadb stores json as string not binary) and my project must be with MySQL or Mariadb because other databases dose not support unsigned integers. and I really need to store my data as unsigned.

I don't know what you're asking at this point.
